# Change Page Template Based on URL Rewrite in WordPress

Tags: templates, page-template

I have created a custom post type author when it takes to single author details it was working fine. For example

http://localhost/author/james/

It was showing single-author.php file. My question is when i am adding a print next to agent name in url for example

http://localhost/author/james/print

If there is print in the url then it needs to automatically redirect to a template present in template directory which is author-print.php

Is this is possible in wordpress ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [page\_template toggle between 2 templates + 2 permalinks for same post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137969/page-template-toggle-between-2-templates-2-permalinks-for-same-post)

Comment: @Milo when it comes to custom post type it was not working it was working for blog posts alone

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you use to register your post type, and anything else you may have tried in solving the problem. It's difficult to say what the problem is if we can't see what you've got.